# After set the location, timezone can't convert

Tags: java

Below is my coding:

```
private final String TIME_ZONE_ID_TRKD_DEFAULT = "Etc/GMT";
private XMLGregorianCalendar getStartDateTime(boolean startFromZeroHour) {
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCal = null;
    try {
        xmlCal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar();
    } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Singapore"));
 now.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(TIME_ZONE_ID_TRKD_DEFAULT));
xmlCal.setDay(now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    xmlCal.setMonth(now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
    xmlCal.setYear(now.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    xmlCal.setTime(now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), now.get(Calendar.MINUTE), now.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

please kindly advice why it can't convert, and how should i do..

Comment: What is the variable *startFromZeroHour* for? It is not used within your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The code cannot be compiled because of an error on the line, where you get the instance of the calendar. I believe you wanted to do this (probably just copy/paste error?):

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Singapore"));
```

Comment: There is also missing the closing braket at the end of the method and a return statement e.g. `return xmlCal;` right in the line before.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach might be the following:

```
private final String TIME_ZONE_ID_TRKD_DEFAULT = "Etc/GMT";

private XMLGregorianCalendar getStartDateTime(boolean startFromZeroHour) {
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCal = null;
    try {
        xmlCal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone(TIME_ZONE_ID_TRKD_DEFAULT)));
    } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    xmlCal.setMillisecond(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
    xmlCal.setTimezone(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);

    if(startFromZeroHour){
        xmlCal.setHour(0);
    }

    return xmlCal;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bug b = new Bug();
    XMLGregorianCalendar startDateTime = b.getStartDateTime(true);
    System.out.println(startDateTime);
    XMLGregorianCalendar startDateTime2 = b.getStartDateTime(false);
    System.out.println(startDateTime2);

}
```

1. First we create a `GregorianCalendar` instance using your timezone constant. It represents the current time (now) if the default constructor is used.
2. Then we use it to initialize the `XMLGregorianCalendar`.
3. You don't want to have the milliseconds and the timezone part, so we just unset them using `DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED` as stated in the JavaDoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html#setMillisecond(int) .

I added a part setting the hour to zero if *startFromZeroHour* is set to **true**. It was not part of your code so you might want to remove or change it.